# How to take multiple values ​separated by spaces with grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following paragraph that arrives in an email and I want to take only those that are by CI

```
CI: CI14710 CI14727 CI14732 CI14741 OC14735 CI14744 Ends\n\n
```

I am trying to use the following regular expression

```
CI: (?<CI>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,})
```

but I only take the first

I tried with this other expression but the logstash fails me

```
CI: (?<CI>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,}.*)\\n\\n
```

it is not seen but they go dobele \ n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below pattern in Grok debugger and able to collect all the words starting with CI.

```
CI: (?<CI>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,}.*) %{GREEDYDATA:data}
```

Output screenshot:

[image]

You can drop the field `data` using the [drop filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html)